# isset returning true on an undefined variable

Tags: php, isset

I'm stumped in an attempt to redirect a user to an authenticated page if they already have a valid session, and to keep them on the login page if not. This line of code either returns null if unauthenticated (no active session), or the url which they will be redirected to. It is returning null.

```
$UserHome = isset($TheUserSession) && $TheUserSession->IsSessionValid() ? $TheUserSession->GetUserHome() : null;
```

What is confusing me is that when I check `isset($TheUserSession)` I get true, but when it checks `$TheUserSession->IsSessionValid()` it throws an error

> Warning: Undefined variable $TheUserSession in ...

How is it possible that `isset()` returns true on an undefined variable?

Comment: Where's the statement where `$TheUserSession` is declared? Just because it exists doesn't mean it will necessarily have the method you are calling on it.

Comment: Ok this is weird. It does not look like $TheUserSession is defined anywhere in this file. I just checked the required classes and none of them define it either. So I am wondering how exactly isset() returns true on a variable that seems non existent?

Comment: `print_r($TheUserSession)` to see what's inside it, and any methods.

Comment: I have had this happen when a method fails to put anything into a variable, like `$TheUserSession = $something->returnedToVariable()` where the class fails to return anything. It sets the variable as `NULL` which will throw an undefined warning when trying to access a method on it.

Comment: Also check this out as well, it helps show how each falsey type is handled by different functions: https://www.danielnorton.com/2013site/nerd/code/php/isdef.html

Comment: Thanks all. So I made some headway. Because this is such a large project, I noticed that the Session class had actually not been included. So I did so and now I'm no longer getting the undeclared issue. However I am getting an invalid session which is a much easier task to handle. Thank you I think I have things sorted out.